# How can I bind a linear-gradient background property made up of dynamic variables constituting the color names, angles, etc?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I keep running into this problem. I need to be able to set the background of various elements in my component as dynamic linear gradients. (The context is creating a grid background that scales and adjusts depending on various inputs).

I want to be able to build up my `linear-gradient` CSS background property dynamically in a function, e.g. here's a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
createBackgroundString(){
    return 'linear-gradient(' + this.angle + 'deg, ' + this.color1 + ', ' + this.color2 + ')';
}
```

...and then stick that into my `:style` attribute to have Vue apply it dynamically:

```
v-bind:style="{ background: createBackgroundString() }"
```

Vue rejects (ignores) this outright, presumably because the resultant string is too complex to fit the property template which expects a simple string like 'red' or '#FF000' etc.

Is there any way/hack/workaround to achieve this in Vue? At the moment I'm having to resort to jQuery for this which is far from ideal.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Is `v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: createBackgroundString() }"` not working?

Comment: @T.Short Yes. It seems to reject any complex linear-gradient string created dynamically (I've just edited the question to clarify this). thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get it to work like this:

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: createBackgroundString }" />
```

and a computed prop:

```js
data() {
    return {
      angle: '50',
      color1: 'red',
      color2: 'blue'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    createBackgroundString() {
      return `linear-gradient(${this.angle}deg, ${this.color1}, ${this.color2})`;
    }
  }
```

You don't have to use backticks (`) if you don't want to. I just prefer it.

> Note that I have changed `createBackgroundString()` to `createBackgroundString`

Comment: You're absolutely right, that *does* work- and now even all my other variant attempts at this seem to work as well! (eh?!) No idea what I was doing wrong before.. thanks for your help!

Comment: I am trying to do almost the same, with no success :( `<div class="light-bar" :style="{background: createBackgroundString}">` and in my computed props this `    createBackgroundString() {
      return '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #64b4a0 0%,#64b4a0 ${this.graphPercentage}%,white ${this.graphPercentage}%,white 100%)';
    }` these percentages are in data, but with no success :(

Comment: Ha I know the reason but no solution, `${}` are not substituted

Comment: I got it, don't know how I fixed it, logic seems same, but your hint is working for me :)

Comment: @Mlok - To use `${}` substitution, you need to contain your string within backticks `\`` rather than single quotes `'`